# 'Context' object has no attribute 'render_context'

Tags: django, django-templates, rendering

I am running Django==3.2.12 and trying to generate a rendered tewmplate string. The following is the nuts and bolts of it....

I am recieving the error "'Context' object has no attribute 'render_context'" and can not make any sence of it.

It used to work fine, I am using django-mjml for this.

Code...

```
    import uuid
    from django.db import models
    from django.template import Template, Context
    from django.urls import reverse


    class EmailTemplate(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
        uuid = models.UUIDField(default = uuid.uuid4)
        mjml_template = models.TextField(blank=True)
        html_template = models.TextField(blank=True)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['name', ]
            verbose_name = 'Template'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Templates'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('pages:emailing', kwargs={'slug': self.slug, 'uuid': self.uuid})

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

            mjml_open = '{% load mjml %}{% mjml %}'
            mjml_close = '{% endmjml %}'

            verbatum_open = '{% verbatim %}{{'
            verbatum_close = '}}{% endverbatim %}'

            verbatum = self.mjml_template.replace('{{', verbatum_open)
            verbatum = verbatum.replace('}}', verbatum_close)
            verbatum = mjml_open + verbatum + mjml_close

            template = Template(verbatum)
            context = Context({})

            passed = False
            try:
                self.html_template = template.render(context)
                passed = True
            except Exception as err:
                self.html_template = str(err)

            if passed:
                image_categories = ImageCategory.objects.filter(templates=self)
                for image_category in image_categories:
                    for image in image_category.get_images():
                        tag = '[~ ' + image.slug + ' ~]'
                        swap = self.html_template
                        swap = swap.replace(tag, image.image.url)
                        self.html_template = swap

                resource_categories = ResourceCategory.objects.filter(templates=self)
                for resource_category in resource_categories:
                    for resource in resource_category.get_resources():
                        tag = '[~ ' + resource.slug + ' ~]'
                        swap = self.html_template
                        swap = swap.replace(tag, resource.resource)
                        self.html_template = swap

            super(EmailTemplate, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Traceback....

```
    Internal Server Error: /admin/emailing/emailtemplate/1/change/
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/sbrown/.local/share/virtualenvs/mjml-NNm5TF3H/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/Users/sbrown/.local/share/virtualenvs/mjml-NNm5TF3H/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "/Users/sbrown/.local/share/virtualenvs/mjml-NNm5TF3H/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 616, in wrapper
        return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/sbrown/.local/share/virtualenvs/mjml-NNm5TF3H/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/sbrown/.local/share/virtualenvs/mjml-NNm5TF3H/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/sbrown/.local/share/virtualenvs/mjml-NNm5TF3H/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 232, in inner
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/sbrown/.local/share/virtualenvs/mjml-NNm5TF3H/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1660, in change_view
        return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
      File "/Users/sbrown/.local/share/virtualenvs/mjml-NNm5TF3H/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
        return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/sbrown/.local/share/virtualenvs/mjml-NNm5TF3H/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/sbrown/.local/share/virtualenvs/mjml-NNm5TF3H/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1540, in changeform_view
        return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
      File "/Users/sbrown/.local/share/virtualenvs/mjml-NNm5TF3H/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1586, in _changeform_view
        self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
      File "/Users/sbrown/.local/share/virtualenvs/mjml-NNm5TF3H/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1099, in save_model
        obj.save()
      File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mjml/emailing/models.py", line 42, in save
        self.html_template = template.render(context)
      File "/Users/sbrown/.local/share/virtualenvs/mjml-NNm5TF3H/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 166, in render
        with context.render_context.push_state(self):
    AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'render_context'
```

Comment: Always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Comment: Traceback added.

Comment: Obviously your actual code is different than the one you posted above: `self.html_template = template.render(context)`. Please post your actual code and not a hypothetical one. Are you sure you import the correct `Context` class?

Comment: Code from the Model and imports added.

Comment: Moved code to its onw section, as you probably didn't see it attached to the Traceback.

Comment: To be honest: This confuses me a lot. I checked everything and your code looks legit. I tried to lookup the sourcecode of your django version, but [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/template/context.py) at least I can find the `render_context` attribute. Something has to be wrong with your instanciating of the `Context` object. Could you check the entire views.py file if you maybe overrode that import statement of `Context`. Make sure you did no copy-paste error from your code to stackoverflow, because in here everything looks legit.